# Paypal express checkout with validation is not working as expected?

Tags: paypal

It was working fine till morning. What happened to this demo? Validation is not supposed to be working as before?

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/validation

It should validate first before it opens up a popup.

Answer (score 0):

I think the client ID is extinct. When I am changing the client ID, It started working.

Don't rely on demos. PayPal changes its demos once in a while.

Comment: No, it does not. It should always show an error message. It should not pop up. Changing the client ID would not have any impact over these issues.